# How to offer software license discounts to students with confirmation?

Tags: software, business-plan, licensing, startups, registration

I hope this is the right place. I'm a few months away from releasing my first software product that is not SaaS, but downloadable (engineering visualization tool) and am working on ideas about how to do marketing. One option I'd like to offer is a discount for students in universities, otherwise, I think my software would not be affordable for students and not sure they have other options.

I'm not sure how people usually go about verifying a purchase, or that the person is a student and not just someone trying to get a discount. If I sell a license, I can only imagine it is done by registering their email address which should be using a university domain? Is that right? Other thoughts on this?

Comment: https://github.com/Hipo/university-domains-list

Comment: If you'd like to make than an answer, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use libraries such as [this Github project](https://github.com/Hipo/university-domains-list) that lists email domains for higher-education institutes. You can also look up some older SWOT repos (there are about 10 or so that are highly used).